# How to iterate through selected HTML table rows and retrieve data from each row

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc, datatables

I am displaying a list of data selected from an Oracle database on a jsp using Spring MVC.

The code for displaying the data in a table is as follows (using datatables plugin):

```
$("#addLocationsTable").DataTable({
  "bProcessing" : false, "bServerSide" : false, "responsive" : true, "sort" : "position", "oLanguage" :
  {
    "sEmptyTable" : "There were no matches found for the search. Try again with different criteria. "
  },
  "sAjaxSource" : "addLocations.htm",
  "responsive": "true",
  "order": [[0, "asc"]],
  aLengthMenu: [
    [25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
    [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
  ],
  iDisplayLength: -1,
  "scrollY":        "200px",
  "scrollCollapse": true,
  "paging":         false,

  "sAjaxDataProp" : "locationData", "bDestroy" : true,
  "aoColumns" :
    [
      {"mData" : "id"},
      {"mData" : "id"}
    ],
  'columnDefs' : [{
    'targets' : 0,
    'searchable':false,
    'orderable':false,
    'className': 'dt-body-center',
    'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
      return '<input type="checkbox" name="selectedID" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
    }
  }]
});
```

This works to assign a checkbox to each row, and assigns the checkbox with the value of the id.  In my controller, I am able to test with the following code, which returns the value of the first selected checkbox:

```
@RequestMapping(params="saveLocations", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveLocations(HttpServletRequest req){
    System.out.println(req.getParameter("selectedID"));
    return "redirect:/locations.htm";
}
```

On the jsp, this submit is handled using a basic submit button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveLocations" name="saveLocations">Save</button>
```

What I am trying to do is retrieve each selected row in the table.  I know that I have to loop through the values somehow, but I'm not really sure how to do that.

ANSWER:  When returning multiple values, you need to use getParameterValues().  So the new controller looks like this:

```
    String[] values = req.getParameterValues("selectedID");
    for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++)
    {
    System.out.println(values[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

You can use the snippet below, where `frm-example` is ID of your form.

It will iterate over all checkboxes in the table and add those not present in DOM as `<input type="hidden">` elements.

```
// Handle form submission event
$('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){
   var form = this;

   // Iterate over all checkboxes in the table
   table.$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
      // If checkbox doesn't exist in DOM
      if(!$.contains(document, this)){
         // If checkbox is checked
         if(this.checked){
            // Create a hidden element 
            $(form).append(
               $('<input>')
                  .attr('type', 'hidden')
                  .attr('name', this.name)
                  .val(this.value)
            );
         }
      } 
   });
});
```

I'm not Java expert but it looks like you need to use [`getParameterValues()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) on the server-side instead of [`getParameter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29). According to the manual [`getParameter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) should be used when there is only one value.

#### DEMO

See [jQuery DataTables: How to submit all pages form data](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-submit-all-pages-form-data/) for more details and demonstration.

Comment: I actually saw this on your site prior to posting my original question.  I attempted to use it, but my controller still just returns the first value.

Comment: @QuestionMarks, I'm not Java expert but it looks like you need to use `getParameterValues` instead of `getParameter`, according to the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) [`getParameter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) should be used when there is only one value.

Comment: BOOM!!  You got it, thanks!  I just had to make a String array of the results, add a "for" loop, and print each result.  Perfect, thank you!

Comment: I added my new controller to my original post using getParameterValues, if you'd like to add that to your answer as well.

Comment: Actually, the javascript piece isn't even necessary when using getParameterValues.